# SVG animation using data file

Tags: animate, dvisvgm

I am trying to create a simple SVG animation using the animate package:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\newcommand\fileopenr[2]{%
    \newread#1%
    \immediate\openin#1=#2%
}
\newcommand\readtolist[3][,]{%
    \setsepchar{#1}%
    \immediate\read#2 to \inputline{%
        \ifeof#2
        \multiframebreak%
        \else%
        \greadlist#3\inputline%
        \fi%
    }%
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{animateinline}[poster=first,autoplay,loop]{25}
        \fileopenr{\dataP}{xP.dat}%
        \readtolist[ ]{\dataP}{\posP}%
        \multiframe{251}{}{%
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\col}{ifthenelse(\posP[3]>=0,"green!50!black","red!50!black")}
                \fill[color=\col] (5,1+0) rectangle ++(\posP[3]/2,0.2);
                \draw[thick, color=black, -latex] (0,0) -- (10,0) node[right]{$x$};
                \node[draw,circle,fill] (goal) at (10/1.5,0) {};
                \fill[color=green] (\posP[1]/1.5,0) rectangle ++(1,0.5);                
            \end{tikzpicture}
            \readtolist[ ]{\dataP}{\posP}%
        }
    \end{animateinline}
\end{document}
```

The file `xP.dat` is a space-separated list of numbers, available [here](https://pastebin.com/DS69xMcX).

This works perfectly when I create an animated PDF using `pdflatex`. But, when I try to create an SVG file by adding the option `\documentclass[dvisvgm]{standalone}` and then running

```
latex filename
latex filename
dvisvgm --exact --font-format=woff --zoom=-1 filename
```

as per the package documentation, I get the error

```
ERROR: error in special: expected '-->' at end of comment
```

and the compiled SVG file is garbage.

What am I missing?

Comment: I can't reproduce the error. The conversion works correctly here. What version of dvisvgm do you use? Please also provide the DVI file. It seems the file contains a raw SVG comment (`<!-- ... -->`) that's not properly closed.

Comment: I am using version 2.11.1 on a Windows 10 PC, should be the latest version available in MiKTeX. The dvi file is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/st073e2fg6fq6fb/simple.dvi?dl=0).

Comment: Hm, your DVI file looks good and also converts without errors on my machine. Maybe it's an issue in the dvisvgm build of MiKTeX. Could you try the separately built binaries provided [here](https://github.com/mgieseki/dvisvgm/releases/tag/2.12)?

Comment: Those are giving me `ERROR: MiKTeX session could not be initialized`. I can run `latex` and `pdflatex` in the same command prompt, so I know the TeX binaries are in my windows PATH. Do I need to do something to get the separately built libraries to work with MiKTeX?

Comment: Do you use the MiKTeX Portable edition? In this case, I'm afraid, you can't use the independent builds. They only work together with the regularly installed version. Also, if you installed the 32 bit version of MiKTeX, you must also use the 32 bit version of dvisvgm. Maybe you should report the error to the MiKTeX developer as well.

Comment: I use the installed (per user, in `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64`) version of 64 bit MiKTeX, and am trying the `win64` version of the binaries.

Comment: Ok, local installations probably don't create global registry entries, so that dvisvgm can't access the MiKTeX session object. Sorry, I can't help with this issue then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [confirmed bug](https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/983) in the `MiKTeX` version of `dvisvgm` as of December, 2021, and the `MiKTeX` team is on it.

In the meantime, the binaries [provided here](https://github.com/mgieseki/dvisvgm/releases/tag/2.12) work, but only if you have `MiKTeX` installed for all users (in `C:/Program Files`).